# Laravel 5.3 to 5.4 relations foreignKey issue

Tags: php, laravel-5

After updating to 5.4, my relations where not working properly anymore. After inspecting I found out Laravel is now looking for different 
foreignKey names:  `user_user_id` or `post_post_id` instead of `user_id`,`post_id` etc. This was working until L 5.3. I also had to update some of my pivot tabels primarykey to tag_tag_id etc in order to get them working again.

I updated my tables foreignkey names according to this new convention and now it's working. But I still would like to know why and how this changed and where it's coming from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you overriding the primary key on your models using `getKeyName` ?

Laravel still uses the same convention `user_id` as the foreign key.

However, in 5.4, you don't need to explicitly specifying the foreign key when defining the relationship.

From the docs:

> Just like previous Laravel releases, this relationship will typically use user_id as the foreign key. However, the behavior could be different from previous releases if you are overriding the  getKeyName method of the User model

[Upgrading To 5.4.0 From 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade)

**Update**

The problem might be caused also by setting the value of  $primaryKey.
You did not submit any code. However, assuming on your user model, you define `$primaryKey = user_id` Laravel will append the column name to this key name. Thus, you see laravel trying to query user_user_id.

Just remove the $keyname from the user model, and laravel will assume the foreign key following the convention user_id.

Or you could define the foreign key explicitly passing a second argument to the belongsTo():

    `return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id);`

Comment: No, I only set the $primaryKey in the user model itself. And load the relation in my post model like this : public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

Comment: Setting the $primaryKey is the same as overriding the getKeyName method which is the cause to your problem.

Comment: Ok, but if I don't set the $primaryKey, it is looking for the column 'id' in my users table, which it won't find because my primary key is 'user_id'. QLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = 26 limit 1). Which would mean I have to change all the primary keys to just 'id'. Then setting the primaryKey to a custom value would be useless

Comment: See the update. You either remove $primaryKey from all models in which case laravel will assume it's 'id'. Or you you tell it which foreign key to use when defining the relationsship.

Comment: Thanks, return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id); works. When removing the primarykey, it won't look for user_id but only id. So I will just define the foreign key in the relationship methods :-)