# Eloquent hasOne relationship Not working laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to keep a relationship between two tables in my database.

Users Table:

```
Id User_id Name
```

Contacts Table:

```
Id User_Id contacts
```

I am saving multiple contacts in the contacts table. Now i want to retrieve all the contacts saved to the User_ID. For that, i am trying to establish a hasOne relationship but i get a error for the following code can someone let me know what i am doing wrong? I am following the official documentation for this.

User model:

```
class users extends Model
{
   protected $table = "users";
   public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\contacts','User_Id');
    }
}
```

Contacts Model:

```
class contacts extends Model
{
    public $table = "contacts";

    public function Users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Users','User_id');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function eloquentget(){

        $contacts = Users::find(1)->contacts->first();
        return response()->json($contacts,200);
    }
```

When i try this code in postman i get an Exception :

```
ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object
```

What am i doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why is there both an `id` and `User_Id` on the users table? Also your choice of names and particularly cases in non-standard, you should consider following the Laravel recommendations w.r.t. naming

Comment: Once the code is working you might want to run it by the folks on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get some feed back on naming conventions and table structure as suggested by @apokryfos. There are a few things you should probably change to make your life easier in the future.

Comment: I am using the id in the contacts table to edit seperate contacts. As i have multiple of them using the same user_id.

Comment: have you updated from 5.3 to 5.4? I had a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994022/laravel-5-3-to-5-4-relations-foreignkey-issue

Answer (score 2):

Since you are saving multiple Contacts for any given User then you are using the wrong relation. You need to setup a One-Many relationship using `hasMany()`.

```
class users extends Model
{
   protected $table = "users";
   public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\contacts','User_Id','User_Id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. But now I get a User data but I am not getting the contacts data. It's null. `contacts: []`

Comment: Try `return $this->hasMany('App\contacts','User_Id', 'User_Id');`

Comment: Yup that did it. Can you tell me why i need to do that?

Comment: By default Laravel assumes the value in the `id` column is used as the foreign key in the related table. In your user table you are using `User_Id` instead of the `Id` column to link your tables. To indicate this to Laravel you need to use the third argument to the `hasMany()` function to set the local key.

Comment: How can i use orderBy and where clause for the contact details From this?? and how can i use two different calls for orderBy and Where clause on contacts table? Please clarify this doubt for me.

Comment: Yes you can use` orderBy()` and `where()` clauses. You should probably post a new question about this where you can show the code you have tried and give a more detailed description of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
class users extends Model
{
   protected $table = "users";

   public function contacts()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\contacts','User_Id','User_Id');
   }
}
```

And on your controller, You can use it like this

```
$contacts= User::find(1)->contacts; // it will return an array of collection
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use ->first(); because you already used relation hasOne

just use :

$contacts = Users::find(1)->contacts;

return response()->json($contacts,200);